# Sprite Not Moving

Tags: c#, xna

I am working on a game, and the spaceship is supposed to move when I press right and left. Unfortunately, this is not working well. Here is the code that I think is relevant, if you need the rest, just ask.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;  
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;

namespace thedodger
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    int scorevalue = 0;
    SpriteFont font;

    List<gameObject> objectList = new List<gameObject>();
    Random rand = new Random(1);
    Asteroid asteroid;
    public static int screenHeight = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height;
    public static int screenWidth =GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
    int asteroidCount = 0;
    Player player = new Player();


    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");


        gameObject.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("asteroid");
        Player.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("EnemyShip005");


        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        scorevalue++;

        player.Update(gameTime);

        if (rand.Next(0, 8) == 2 && asteroidCount < 50)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                asteroid = new Asteroid(rand.Next(32,screenWidth));
                objectList.Add(asteroid);
                asteroidCount++;


            }
        }

        foreach (Asteroid asteroid in objectList)
        {
            asteroid.Update(gameTime);

        }



        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
         spriteBatch.Begin();
         spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + scorevalue, new Vector2(5, 5), Color.White);
         foreach (Asteroid asteroid in objectList)
         {

             asteroid.Draw(spriteBatch);
         }
         player.Draw(spriteBatch);
         spriteBatch.End();



        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;

namespace thedodger
{

class Player
{
    public static Texture2D texture;

    int xPos = 100;
    int yPos = 100;

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(xPos,yPos,75,59), Color.White);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState keyboard = new KeyboardState();

        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            xPos--;
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            xPos++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does it move at all? Or are you just saying that it's moving very slowly? If moving slowly is what you're complaining about, try changing `xPos--;` to `xPos -= 10;`

Answer (score 7):

In `Player.Update`, you are doing `new KeyboardState()` - I think this is giving you an empty keyboard state object. Try using `Keyboard.GetState()` instead.